# Laravel JWT auth get User ID when refreshing token

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, jwt

I'm using the tymon jwt-auth package and am utilising refresh tokens. My database has a column for when a user last logged in, which is set upon log in to my app, but I need to update this column when the user's token is refreshed.

I'm having some trouble getting the `id` of the user, so that I know to update their record, `Auth::id()` is null, and thus never runs.

Even if I run this after doing a refresh. How can I obtain the user to update their last logged in column?

```php
/**
 * Refresh a token.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
 */
public function refresh()
{
    try {
        if (Auth::id()) {
            ProcessLastUserLogin::dispatch(
                Auth::id(), Carbon::now()
            );
        } else {
            Log::debug('unable to obtain user ID');
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) { }

    // return refresh token
    return $this->respondWithToken(auth()->refresh(), true);
}
```

#### UPDATE

I've tried the following:

```php
public function refresh()
{
    $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
    Log::debug('user', [
        'user' => $user
    ]);
    return $this->respondWithToken(auth()->refresh());
}
```

No user is logged upon token refresh, error thrown:

> [2021-10-15 14:41:11] local.ERROR: Token has expired {"exception":"[object] (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException(code: 0): Token has expired at /Users/ryanholton/Sites/project-beacon-api/vendor/tymon/jwt-auth/src/Claims/Expiration.php:31)
> [stacktrace]

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced with same  problem like you.
Most probably you are importing JWTAuth class from `use Tymon\JWTAuth\JWTAuth`.
If i am right, then you just need to use `use Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth;`
Hope it will resolve your problem.